# Running Spring Boot Admin with a non-default port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I want to start the Spring Boot Admin server on a different port than 8080.
So I configured the server.port property in the bootstrap.yml file with 9000, but still the server listens on port 8080 according to the log file.
Here's my bootstrap.yml:

```
server:
  port: 9000

spring:
  application:
    name: admin-server
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

And this is the final part of the console log:

```
2018-11-29 15:52:11.242  INFO 25999 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-11-29 15:52:11.271  INFO 25999 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-11-29 15:52:11.274  INFO 25999 --- [           main] n.d.d.c.a.AdminServerApplication         : Started AdminServerApplication in 2.826 seconds (JVM running for 3.355)
2018-11-29 15:52:11.818  INFO 25999 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-11-29 15:52:11.819  INFO 25999 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-11-29 15:52:11.830  INFO 25999 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 11 ms
```

Comment: Do you also have an application.yml file? The info in there trumps that in boostrap.yml

Comment: Nope, its not there, sources are available in [github](https://github.com/legolas/spring-cloud-demo/tree/master/admin-server).

Answer (score 2):

In the application.properties file put this

```
server.port = 9000
```

Comment: the boostrap.yml should be used when using a config server, as I do. The actual properties are retrieved through the config server.

Comment: Just to verify I added an application.properties with server.port=9000 and that did the trick.
But I want to have this configurable using the config service. So I'm still searching for a proper solution.
The other components do use the bootstrap.yml files just fine.

Answer (score 2):

A flashlight in my brain told me I might have forgotten to add the `spring-cloud-config-client` dependency, after checking, and then adding the appropriate dependency to the `pom.xml`, it worked like a charm:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Thanks to all for providing feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Many different configuration sources have precedence over `application.properties` (or YAML) as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

You might need to verify if one of those sources are not interfering with the value of `serve.port`.

Comment: Thanks @Gustavo, I’ll have a look at the doc.